# Effective ways how to get data from the server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

We are building webapp and I have troubles deciding how to get data from the server. 
On frontend we have angularJS and HTML. On the backend we have NodeJS, MongoDB, Mongoose and Express. As a templating engine we user JADE.
Now, what is the best way to fill the templates? Getting the data on the server while loading the partial or load the data through AngularJS using $http?

I am looking for the most effective and fastest way. Any thoughts?

Comment: What way meets the needs of your application and users? If you're using Angular, I don't understand how you're also using JADE (and how you'd use it in a single-page-application which would be typical of an Angular application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to separate the things a bit. Keep your backend independent and create an REST API which provides the data. Once this is done you may use simply http request to access the data. By following this approach you will be later able to use other frameworks or even other languages to get the information stored into your database.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing client-side and server-side composition of content can be optimized in a broad sense if your infrastructure includes reverse proxies and such.  I am speaking very broadly here, but things with less state, and less coupling of state to quickly changing data, can be moved closer to the edge of infrastructure and cached and vended to clients calling http "on their own."    An example might be this hour's set of suggested products for a user profile independent of the actual buying that a customer is performing.  The closer you get to data and activity that is bespoke to the user and very transactional in nature, the more you need to go deep to the server side to ensure information archtecture consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There's really *no need* to use any kind of serverside html rendering when using Angular; just serve some old skool plain html files on any webserver and grab your data using $resource or $http. It's **lightning fast** -- there's no faster way than only transferring the essential data to the browser.

Besides, *serverside rendering is soooooo 2012*